# Como seleccionar un texto que no tiene, clases, id o incluso etiquetas de html o css?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Muy buenas amigos de STACKOVERFLOW, Necesito ayuda y espero me puedan ayudar a posteridad; me encontrado muchos casos donde los clientes me piden traducir algo que por mucho que lo intente en woocommerce de wordpress no me lo permite, e utilizado el plugind de "loco translate" y este dice ya estar traducido, e navegado por el administrador de archivos hasta el archivo responsable y nada, e utilizado dreamweaver y nada; de verdad que no entiendo? lo único que me permite hacer modificaciones es trabajar con CSS, pero me encuentro con el siguiente inconveniente. Cmo poder realizar cambio allí o traducir ese texto?.. Un Abrazo!!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, como ya sabes el código va como texto por favor

Comment: Si pones el código como texto, nos facilitas las tareas, en tu caso sería, usando jquery: $("#order_comments_fields > label").text();

Answer (score 0):

Lamento decirte que no hay forma de tomar ese texto, si no está dentro de una etiqueta para modificarlo.

Lo que debes es colocarlo dentro una etiqueta **span** o una **p** para poder que el documento HTML sea leído de forma correcta.

Comment: Estimado, es una pregunta de 2021. Gracias

Comment: @Liyo no es problema que la pregunta sea vieja. Lo que sí hay que evitar es responder a preguntas de muy baja calidad. Para el autor de la respuesta: lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas bien formadas_.